# How to interact between classes

Tags: iphone, ios

A very basic question on how to interact between classes here: how can I trigger an action called by clicking on a button linked to one class (the graphic user interface in my case - which does not contain any drawing code) inside another class (my drawing class - which is defined programmatically)?

Thanks!

Edited: I have tried to implement the solutions suggested below but I didn't manage to trigger the action from the other class. I have two classes: the main view controller and a class with the drawing code. Any advice would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

```
//MainViewController.m
//This class has a xib and contains the graphic user interface

- (void)ImageHasChanged
{        
//do something on the GUI
}


//DrawView.m
//This class has no associated xib and contains the drawing code

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
 //I want to call ImageHasChanged from MainViewController.m here
 //How can I do this?
}
```

Comment: Can you throw up some code please?  I'm not 100% sure what your situation is.  We'll be able to help you more if you insert the relevant code into your question.  Thanks!

Comment: I have added some code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inter-class functionality is done simply by importing one class into the other, and calling an accessible method/instance variable on the import.

For the button IBAction example in your question:

**ClassA.m (This will be imported via its header):**

```
#import "ClassA.h"
@implementation ClassA

// This is a class-level function (indicated by the '+'). It can't contain
// any instance variables of ClassA though!
+(void)publicDrawingFunction:(NSString *)aVariable { 
    // Your method here...
}

// This is a instance-level function (indicated by the '-'). It can contain
// instance variables of ClassA, but it requires you to create an instance
// of ClassA in ClassB before you can use the function!
-(NSString *)privateDrawingFunction:(NSString *)aVariable {
    // Your method here...
}
@end
```

**ClassB.m (This is your UI class that will call the other method):**

```
#import "ClassA.h"  // <---- THE IMPORTANT HEADER IMPORT!

@implementation ClassB

// The IBAction for handling a button click
-(IBAction)clickDrawButton:(id)sender {

    // Calling the class method is simple:
    [ClassA publicDrawingFunction:@"string to pass to function"];

    // Calling the instance method requires a class instance to be created first:
    ClassA *instanceOfClassA = [[ClassA alloc]init];
    NSString *result = [instanceOfClassA privateDrawingFunction:@"stringToPassAlong"];

    // If you no longer require the ClassA instance in this scope, release it (if not using ARC)! 
    [instanceOfClassA release];

}
@end
```

Side note: If you're going to require ClassA a lot in ClassB, consider creating a class-wide instance of it in ClassB to re-use wherever it's required. Just don't forget to release it in dealloc (or maybe set it to `nil` in ARC) when you're finished with it!

Finally, please consider reading through the [Apple Docs on Objective-C classes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH1-SW2) (and indeed all other sections of the documentation relevant to what you're trying to achieve). It is a bit time-consuming, but very well invested in the long run into building your confidence as an Objective-C programmer!

Comment: Public and private are not the correct terms to describe the + and - symbols.  - functions are instance-level functions; they operate on and can modify each instance of the class.  + functions are class-level functions; whatever they do, they cannot modify instance variables of the class.  Technically all methods in Obj-C are public.  You can use a category to make pseudo-private methods, but even these can be called if their name is known by the programmer, since Obj-c as a language technically doesn't make function calls; it sends messages.

Comment: Had a feeling I was getting those wrong! Thanks for pointing that out, I've edited the code sample to prevent spreading misinformation.

Comment: @Andeh, you might want to release the *instance* of ClassA, not the class itself. (I guess you knew that, but maybe the OP didn't.)

Comment: @matsr correct you are, that's what I get for typing code directly into SO! I did mean the instance but my brain had other plans. Fixed now

Comment: Top notch explanations. Thank you so much

Comment: More specificity would be helpful. What happens when you run it? Does XCode show any warnings? Did you ensure you're importing mainViewController.h inside DrawView.m? Why is `ImageHasChanged` an IBAction if it's called from another function and not directly from user input?

Comment: You are right. Code edited. I changed it from IBAction to void (I was triggering it from a button in mainViewController for debugging purposes as I was not able to trigger it from DrawView). Yes I did import mainViewController.h inside DrawView. When I run it nothing happens yet as the problem is that I don't know the right syntax to trigger the method from DrawView.m (I would be using [self ImageHasChanged] if it was in the same class).

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply! Glad to hear you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

//As you said an instance of MainViewController has to be created first

```
MainViewController *instanceOfMainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc]init];
[instanceOfMainViewController ImageHasChanged];
```

//Thanks for your help Andeh!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use @protocol(Delegate) to interact message between two classes this is standard way  Or refer this document
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html to learn more